# Does tab completion work in catkin workspaces under groovy?

Tags: catkin, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a dual catkin / rosbuild set up according to
ros.org/wiki/catkin/Tutorials/using_rosbuild_with_catkin

For nodes build under catkin, using roscd takes me to the
build/repo/package/catkin_generated/stamps/package folder.

It seems all of the build stuff is working, and I can execute the files (roslaunch/rosrun) if I give the complete filenames (e.g. rosrun package node), but the tab auto complete that works with rosbuild systems does not function properly.

To be clear, autocomplete works fine for anything built with rosbuild, but not for the catkinized packages.

I am calling the setup.bash from the rosbuild workspace.

Do I have something set up wrong, or is the tab complete functionality lost in catkin?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57363/does-tab-completion-work-in-catkin-workspaces-under-groovy?/) by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 476 on 2013-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know the tab completion only works for the workspace you sourced. If you source the setup.bash in the catkin workspace, you will be able to use autocompletion for all your catkin packages.

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) on 2013-03-07**:
OK this is working now.  On computer at work, I'm seeing both catkin_ws and rosbuild_ws.  Last night, the system at home was showing me only rosbuild, and not the catkin_ws.  Now I'm confused as to what the difference is in the setup at home.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-03-07**:
This could be that the rospack cache was out of date. You can manually refresh the rospack cache by doing `rospack profile`, or you can wait as the cache expires every minute also.